# Error in my code ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'emnist'

Tags: python

When I run my code in Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda, the following error appeared:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'emnist'

How can I solve it?

Comment: Run `pip install emnist` in terminal, then restart your code editor

Answer (score 0):

In order to run modules in Python, you have to install them.
To do that in your case enter the following:

`pip install emnist`

or

`pip3 install emnist`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but it didn't work for me instead I found this solution 
https://anaconda.org/hahaaenois/emnist